# await have to execute chained method one is async(.find) and other is sync (.cahe()) so but cache (second method is executed first) then find?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In overview function we called await Tour.find().cache() so find should be called first then cache but the first acutally cache is executed first then find method ? Is this because
await is executing sync and async function it first exeution sync then async (yes without escaping to next line of code ) or it is something else

Here is handler function (Overview.js)
exports.getOverview = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {

Can you explain why this is not executing the way I think?
const tours = await Tour.find().cache();
res.status(200).render("overview", {
title: "All Tours",
tours,
});
});

Here is function defined in exec.js
const { exec } = mongoose.Query.prototype;

```
    mongoose.Query.prototype.cache = function () {
      this.useCache = true;
      return this;
    };
    
    
    mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function () {
      
      if (!this.useCache) return exec.apply(this, arguments);
    
      
      const key = JSON.stringify(
        Object.assign({}, this.getQuery(), {
          collection: this.mongooseCollection.name,
        })
      );
    
      
      const cacheValue = await client.get(key);
    
    
      if (cacheValue) {
        const doc = JSON.parse(cacheValue);
        return Array.isArray(doc) ? doc.map((d) => this.model(d)) : this.model(doc);
      }
    
      // if we do, return that
    
      // Otherwise, issue the query and store the result in redis
    
      const result = await exec.apply(this, arguments);
    
      client.set(key, JSON.stringify(result), "Ex", 10);
    
      return result;
    };
```

Comment: You're talking about `await Tour.find().cache();` but have posted the code of `exec`, not of `find`? I don't really get the question. What makes you assume that `find` is executed after `cache`?

Comment: find is inbuild in mongoose and we can use mongoose query due to exec function (this return promise)

Comment: Yes, so what? First `find` is called, then `cache` is called, then `exec` is called and returns a promise. Again, what makes you assume that `find` is executed after `cache`?

Comment: after thinking a lot i understand  that mongoose query nature by default is async(so event loop doesnt get blocked) and when we use await it just let asynchrnous code run in async way but it dont let code escape the particular task in which it attached

Comment: So when mongoose query executed "await Tour.find().cache()" first they make a query object and second they set value in query class object then when they try to escape to next line of code they see await(and when in mongoose a query need to be finally execuluted => it get executed by mongoose exec method)